# Problems with sound in Linux Mint 15 on video

Tags: linux-mint, audio, video

**Problem:**

I think you'll enjoy this fun problem. I set-up a dev/media server. Steps to reproduce:

1. Start up any video file (with Banshee or VLC or xfce player - doesn't matter) -- all is well. Sound plays properly.
2. Pause the file. Unpause. Sound stops and there is no way of bringind it back.

That's problem nr 1. Now after playing this file, try to start up another video file:

- Play another file in Banshee/Integrated/XBMC. There is no sound.
- Play another file in VLC, you'll get get a ~0.2s looping white noise instead of the sound. Also, when changing the VLC volume by mouse or keyboard (in steps), it will temporarily change the volume (for like 1s) and the revert back to 87%. When changind the volume by the VLC slider, the volume stays at that level.

**And the most interesting thing:** If I play another audio application (tested only with a browser playing Grooveshark) before opening the second file, the sound will be proper (with the aforementioned pause caveat). This has no effect on the pause bug (i.e. pausing the video, then playing other audio with the browser and unpausing does **not** fix the sound).

**Config:**

- Mainboard: FM2-A75IA
- CPU: A10 5800K (with Radeon HD 7660D)
- OS: Linux Mint 15 with Xfce or straight up XBMC 13
- Latest ATI catalyst drivers - stable (13.4)
- Display: A 42 inch Panasosic plasma connected via HDMI

Comment: Are you using the pulseaudio setup that came with mint or did you tweak anything?

Comment: I did not tweak anything apart from changing the default audio output to HDMI (with pavucontrol).

Comment: Also, I've already tried resetting the pulseaudio settings by deleting the proper config directory.